# Parse \f as string in json

Tags: javascript, json

How do I make this work?

```
JSON.parse('{"value":"I= \\frac{P*R*T}{100}"}')
```

to output

```
{ value: 'I= \frac{P*R*T}{100}' }
```

works in Node REPL, but does not work in the browser.

Comment: Works for me in browser.

Comment: @Tushar which browser???

Comment: Latest Chrome. .

Comment: @Tushar mine does not work.  can you post the output??

Comment: have you tried with `JSON.parse('{"value":"I= \\\\frac{P*R*T}{100}"}')` ?

Comment: @ravisachaniya no. let me try

Comment: @Tushar It's not giving expected output. the output is `Object {value: "I= rac{P*R*T}{100}"}`

Comment: @ravisachaniya JSON.parse('{"value":"I= \\\\frac{P*R*T}{100}"}') worked for me.

Comment: @ricky I am getting the same output.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"value":"I= \\\\frac{P*R*T}{100}"}')` works fine

Comment: @ravisachaniya Can you explain why so many escapes???

Comment: @besrabasant Backslash is replaced with \\ and Form feed is replaced with \f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
JSON.parse('{"value":"I= \\\\frac{P*R*T}{100}"}')
```

> JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape character

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript
- https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

Comment: @besrabasant because you want to escape the "\" and it requires "\\" two times.

Comment: but you are using `\\\` three times.